# Efficiently compute mean and standard deviation from a frequency table

Tags: r, statistics, mean

Suppose I have the following frequency table.

```
> print(dat)
V1    V2
1  1 11613
2  2  6517
3  3  2442
4  4   687
5  5   159
6  6    29

# V1 = Score
# V2 = Frequency
```

How can I efficiently compute the Mean and standard deviation?
Yielding: SD=0.87 MEAN=1.66.
Replicating the score by frequency takes too long to compute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mean is easy.  SD is a little trickier (can't just use fastmean() again because there's an n-1 in the denominator.

```
> dat <- data.frame(freq=seq(6),value=runif(6)*100)
> fastmean <- function(dat) {
+   with(dat, sum(freq*value)/sum(freq) )
+ }
> fastmean(dat)
[1] 55.78302
> 
> fastRMSE <- function(dat) {
+   mu <- fastmean(dat)
+   with(dat, sqrt(sum(freq*(value-mu)^2)/(sum(freq)-1) ) )
+ }
> fastRMSE(dat)
[1] 34.9316
> 
> # To test
> expanded <- with(dat, rep(value,freq) )
> mean(expanded)
[1] 55.78302
> sd(expanded)
[1] 34.9316
```

Note that `fastRMSE` calculates `sum(freq)` twice.  Eliminating this would probably result in another minor speed boost.

**Benchmarking**

```
> microbenchmark(
+   fastmean(dat),
+   mean( with(dat, rep(value,freq) ) )
+   )
Unit: microseconds
                               expr    min      lq median     uq    max
1                     fastmean(dat) 12.433 13.5335 14.776 15.398 23.921
2 mean(with(dat, rep(value, freq))) 21.225 22.3990 22.714 23.406 86.434
> dat <- data.frame(freq=seq(60),value=runif(60)*100)
> 
> dat <- data.frame(freq=seq(60),value=runif(60)*100)
> microbenchmark(
+   fastmean(dat),
+   mean( with(dat, rep(value,freq) ) )
+   )
Unit: microseconds
                               expr    min     lq  median      uq     max
1                     fastmean(dat) 13.177 14.544 15.8860 17.2905  54.983
2 mean(with(dat, rep(value, freq))) 42.610 48.659 49.8615 50.6385 151.053
> dat <- data.frame(freq=seq(600),value=runif(600)*100)
> microbenchmark(
+   fastmean(dat),
+   mean( with(dat, rep(value,freq) ) )
+   )
Unit: microseconds
                               expr      min       lq    median       uq       max
1                     fastmean(dat)   15.706   17.489   25.8825   29.615    79.113
2 mean(with(dat, rep(value, freq))) 1827.146 2283.551 2534.7210 2884.933 26196.923
```

The replicating solution appears to be O( N^2 ) *in the number of entries.*

[image: Replicating solution]

The `fastmean` solution appears to have a 12ms or so fixed cost after which it scales beautifully.

**More benchmarking**

```
Comparison with dot product.

dat <- data.frame(freq=seq(600),value=runif(600)*100)
dbaupp <- function(dat) {
  total.count <- sum(dat$freq)
  as.vector(dat$freq %*% dat$value) / total.count
}
microbenchmark(
  fastmean(dat),
  mean( with(dat, rep(value,freq) ) ),
  dbaupp(dat)
)

Unit: microseconds
                               expr     min       lq   median       uq       max
1                       dbaupp(dat)  20.162  21.6875  25.6010  31.3475   104.054
2                     fastmean(dat)  14.680  16.7885  20.7490  25.1765    94.423
3 mean(with(dat, rep(value, freq))) 489.434 503.6310 514.3525 583.2790 30130.302
```

Answer (score 7):

I might be missing something, but this seems to work very quickly, even substituting millions in the frequency column:

```
dset <- data.frame(V1=1:6,V2=c(11613,6517,2442,687,159,29))
mean(rep(dset$V1,dset$V2))
#[1] 1.664102
sd(rep(dset$V1,dset$V2))
#[1] 0.8712242
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
> m = sum(dat$V1 * dat$V2) / sum(dat$V2)
> m
[1] 1.664102
> sigma = sqrt(sum((dat$V1 - m)**2 * dat$V2) / (sum(dat$V2)-1))
> sigma
[1] 0.8712242
```

No replication here.

Answer (score 5):

The following code doesn't use replication, and it uses R builtins (for the dot product especially) as much as possible so it is probably more efficient that solutions that use `sum(V1 * V2)`. (Edit: this is possibly false: @gsk3's solution seems to be about 1.5 - 2 times faster from my testing.)

### Mean

The definition of mean (or expectation) is `sum(n * freq(n)) / total.count` where `n` is the "score" and `freq(n)` is the frequency of `n` (`total.count` is just `sum(freq(n))`). The sum in the numerator is precisely the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the scores with the frequencies.

The dot product in R is `%*%` (it returns a matrix, but this can basically be treated at a vector for most purposes):

```
> total.count <- sum(dat$V2)
> mean <- dat$V1 %*% dat$V2 / total.count
> mean
         [,1]
[1,] 1.664102
```

### SD

There is a formula at [the end of this section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Generalizing_from_two_numbers), which translates to the following code

```
> sqrt(dat$V1^2 %*% dat$V2 / total.count - mean^2)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.8712039
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's any faster (see my benchmarking).  I rather disagree with the implication that built-ins are always faster (see `mean()`!).  But it's a lovely solution and it scales nicely.

Comment: @gsk3, nope, `total.count` is the total number of things/samples so `dat$V2`. And yep, I had literally just done some benchmarking myself and had come to the same conclusion (I was just editing my answer to that affect). It's a little peculiar that the operation that gives R more information (i.e. `%*%`) is slower than the naive one!

Comment: Oh that's funny.  I'd been working on the opposite premise when I made up my example, but the initial question clearly states V2 is frequency.  Didn't matter since I renamed them anyway :-).  And it's unfortunate that R built-ins are not always (often?) optimized for speed.  I wish someone would spend some time optimizing things for Summer of Code or something.

Comment: It looks like [Julia](http://julialang.org/) might be an appropriate substitute sometime soon (and they are focusing on performance from the start!). Also, taking out the `as.vector` calls makes them a little faster (but not as fast as I thought, if anyone saw my edit, haha).

Comment: Oh no, not another Julia debate! :-D  Personally I think it will take a decade to catch up to R's library of statistical algorithms.  A lot can happen in a decade (including someone going through and optimizing key parts of R's core).

Comment: @gsk3 - If I was to try it in one such hypothetical optimized version, I'd find that the two algorithms run at pretty much the same speed and about 1.6x faster than `fastmean` ;-)

Comment: @Tommy , no, didn't you know that all Julia code is at least 60x faster than R code that the Julia creators wrote to compare it against?  Here's their version: `Rmean <- function(dat) { Sys.sleep(10); fastmean(dat) }`

Comment: Haha, I agree with you that R has a lot of specialist algorithms and that Julia's R "benchmark" code is crappy. But as far as I understand it, the R core is crufty and idiosyncratic, so diving in to optimise it is much easier said than done! (Although, it looks there are some [JITs](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/ra/) for (subsets of) R, and a JIT is the way to make R properly fast.)

Comment: Compiling has been strongly incorporated into R since at least 2.14.  Seems to result in ~30% gains.  But the huge speedups seem to come from re-writing functions that are used a lot to be more sensible (e.g. http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/new-patches-to-speed-up-r-2-13-0/ ).  I suspect that bringing R up to C++ speeds would be impossible, but 2-4x speed gains should be achievable if there were a concerted effort to focus on speed.

Comment: Yeah, 30% isn't very significant (and it's only compiling to bytecode, isn't it?). Like [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) for Python, the biggest improvements will getting a JITing interpreter, this would basically speed up any/all R code with numerical stuff, without having to drop down to C/C++ (so you can keep the niceties/expressiveness of R) or individually optimise each function. In fact, just thinking about it, it wouldn't be completely ridiculous to write an R interpreter in RPython (from the PyPy project), which would result in a JITing compiler for R which could still use the R libraries.